# How to prevent pushes when the system alert is open

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

I need to handle the pushes only if it was opened by taping on it.
So I check if the application was not active when push came

```
if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive {
   // my code 
}
```

but if a system dialog pops up, such as a “request for access to geolocation,” if at that moment a push comes

but if a system dialog pops up, such as a “request for access to geolocation”, if a push arrives at that moment, then the application will be seen under the system dialog, but will consider itself inactive

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive // it TRUE
```

How can I determine this?